# Meaning of ~ in C define

Tags: c, literals, tilde

I'm looking into an example application and I found this literal:

```
#define OFS_INIT            {{(UINT16)0u},{(UINT16)~(UINT16)0u}}

void main( void )
{
    LOCAL_STATIC(, RDS_UINT16,  u16_msgOfs, OFS_INIT);
}
```

I don't have the definition of `LOCAL_STATIC` and I'm tring to understand how it works with `OFS_INIT`.

Comment: Do you know what the `~` operator does?

Comment: @dbush no I mean the C pre-processor output.

Comment: There is nothing preprocessor specific here except the `#define`. It is simply replacing `OFS_INIT` with the thing on the right which looks like an array or `struct` initializer.

Comment: All the preprocessor will do is replace `OFS_INIT` with `{{(UINT16)0u},{(UINT16)~(UINT16)0u}}`.

Comment: Your code after the edit looks invalid. Is it a real code? `OFS_INIT` only makes sense as an initializer.

Comment: If you search the code for where `OFS_INIT` is used it will probably make more sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh: you get the point! Could you please explain how the macro is used to initialize an array or a struct?

Comment: It looks like a `struct` initializer which would make sense. Initializing a `uint16_t` with that does not make sense.

Comment: It is using the same syntax as `{{0}, {0}}`, just with a bunch of casts and the negation operator.

Comment: @EugeneSh. the second would probably be `USHORT_MAX`

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 Yeah, I just show the syntax, not the resulting values

Comment: @EugeneSh. Thanks. I updated the question. And just for my understanding, why I would like to iniatilize a struct element {(UINT16)~(UINT16)0u}?

Comment: We don't know what your `struct` is. Show it, so we don't guess

Comment: @Federico depends entirely on what `LOCAL_STATIC` does with it, and what exactly the `struct` definition is.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 unfortunately I don't have the full code and I'm tring to understand what the programmer did. In detail I don't know what "RDS_UINT16" is. I think it is a uint16_t but in this case, why I  should initialize it with {{(UINT16)0u},{(UINT16)~(UINT16)0u}}?

Comment: *"I don't have the definition of LOCAL_STATIC"* - Compile with -E and then you have it

Comment: *"I don't have the full code and I'm tring to understand what the programmer did."* - You should ask the programmer directly instead. It's very hard to just guess such things. Especially since the code can be wrong.

Comment: This is incredibly bad code. I would strongly recommend staying clear of it. If you want a code review of this little snippet I can give one - it won't be kind. But that doesn't answer your question, so...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `LOCAL_STATIC` is a macro that can be used to declare a variable of a struct type whose fields are typed with one of the argument and initialised with a given value.

Probably this would declare something like:

```
some_struct_type_related_to_RDS_UINT16 u16_msgOfs = OFS_INIT;
```

where `OFS_INIT` defines the initial value of the struct : `{ {0}, {0xFFFF} }`.

Comment: Thanks! It is clear now.

Comment: "is a macro that can be used to declare a variable of a struct type" Or it's some goo in the form of (multi-dim) arrays, compound literals, who knows. That's why we shouldn't invent secret macro languages but stick to C, since the latter can actually be read by C programmers.